# Button List inside the DataList control

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, datalist

I am a facing a situation in which I need to use something like a `ButtonList` inside a `DataList` control.

Since there is no control like `ButtonList`, should I nest a `DataList/Repeater` inside the `DataList` or there is some other better option to handle the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you are looking for but this is what I assume you want:

```
YourListItem1 
    ButtonAction1
    ButtonAction2
    ButtonAction3
    ButtonAction4
YourListItem2
    ButtonAction1
    ButtonAction3
YourListItem3
    ButtonAction1
    ButtonAction2
YourListItem3
    ButtonAction3
    ButtonAction4
```

Or something similar?

To produce this you could just have a `DataList` with a `Repeater` inside that contains the buttons you need.  You could implement the `OnDataBinding` event of your `DataList` `(YourListItem)` and then bind the data that produces the buttons based on some data.  Then in the `Repeater` you could implement each button's `OnDataBinding` event and assign the `CommandArguments` with the ID or detail you need to make the button act specific to the row it is on.

This method would allow you to make one function for each button used in your template and the `CommandArgument` would define the details of the action.

Comment: My problem was i needed a list of buttons inside the Datalist control. But thebuttons are populated from DB. I was asking is there some other alternatives available or this is the only option using a DataList or Repeater inside the DataList to bind the buttons. I was actually thinking of creating  dynamic buttons on the item_databounding event. Anyways i will accept the answer